# URL handling inside a template parser class

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, url

I working on a new PHP framework and I am trying to figure out how to get the url and is query string into a global variable that can change each time a new html page is loaded from within its php handler. The goal is to make a url router without using switches or array keys or json data. I want it to be as efficient as possible preferably. any suggestions would be appreciated. I just have no idea where to start. URL handling is a new prospect for me.

Comment: Why not have a look at existing frameworks to get some inspiration? As this is a large task, you need to start anywhere

Comment: I have been "reverse engineering" the bigger cms systems for years but I'm trying to come up with one of my own and the common way its done with array traversing is innefficient for my needs

Comment: Then why not use any other mechanism? You haven't shared any approach yet, so it's pretty difficult to show you where your approach might get improved

Comment: the three files that make up the loader system are on github at https://github.com/desertmountainstudios/Desert-Mountain-Studios.

Comment: Please share everything relevant here in your question